# How do I update to newer versions of cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, upgrade

I have a project using version .99.4 and I'd like to update to version .99.5. Do I essentially have to create a new project from the template and then re-add all my files etc, or is there some easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to create a new project and add the files in again.. There are libraries update and the default has new files.. GameConfig and RootViewController.. App delegate also has some changes based on the new files..